# two buttons with onClick in same place

Tags: android, android-xml

I need to do a two buttons with onClick.That two buttons have to be located in same place.one button for start functionality for voice record onClick and another button for stop functionality onClick.is it possible? If I get any suggestion it will be helpful to me.Thank you.

I searched many SO post and tutorial.I didn't get it.

Comment: I guess you want on button when user presses start text should change to stop and vice versa right?

Comment: @apk no.one button for stop functionality using onClick and another button for start functionality using onclick

Comment: why dont you use single button no need for two buttons

Comment: @apk that is the requirment,they are asking.is it possible?

Comment: check answer it will help you no need for two buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with something like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
     Button buttonStart;
     Button buttonStop;

     protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
         super.onCreate(icicle);

         setContentView(R.layout.content_layout_id);

         buttonStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStart);
         buttonStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStop);
         buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 // Perform action on click
                 //for example mediaPlayer.start(); if you have a media player
             }
         });
         buttonStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
             public void onClick(View v){
                 //do what you want - for example mediaPlayer.stop();
             }
         });
    }
}
```

After your comment: then use a single button and check if it is recording for example:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
     Button button;
     boolean isRecording = false;

     protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
         super.onCreate(icicle);

         setContentView(R.layout.content_layout_id);

         button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton);
         button.setText("Start");
         button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 // Perform action on click
                 if(isRecording == fasle){
                     //start recording
                     isRecording = true; //set the variable to know that it is recording
                     button.setText("Stop");
                 } else {
                     //stop recording
                     isRecording = false; //set the variable to know that it is not recording
                     button.setText("Start");
                 }
             }
         });
    }
}
```

Comment: two buttons have to be located in same place.thats my issue

Comment: take a look at my EDIT

Answer (score 0):

**If you want exactly the same (i.e, 2 buttons)**

You can use a relativelayout, and add both buttons inside it.

You can show / hide them programmatically like:

```
public void onClick(View v) 
    {
      switch(v.getId()) {
      case R.id.btn1:
       btn1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       btn2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     break;

    case R.id.btn2:
     btn2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     btn1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    break;
   }
 }
```

Otherwise, **`you can even use one button for both the functionalities (start and stop)`** as -

```
    public void onClick(View v) 
   {
    if(btn1.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("start"))
    {
        btn1.setText("stop");
        mp2.start();
        musicPlaying = true;
    }
    else if(btn1.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("stop"))
    {
        btn1.setText("start");
        mp2.stop();
        musicPlaying = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: one button with start and stop!! can you show me some link for example?